# How to iterate items in a table using the C API

Tags: c, lua

I'm making a material system for a game engine, and I'm trying to use Lua scripts as essentially config files for materials, so an example material file might look like this:

```lua
material = {
    color = {0.3, 1, 0.2}
    specular_intensity = 0.3
    shininess = 0.1
}
```

But, the values in the table will vary depending on the shader - so I want to iterate over the values in the table, and then attempt to set their values to uniforms in the shader, which means I need the name as well as the value. How can I go about this (I'm using the C API)?

Comment: `C API` Why is this tagged `C++`?

Comment: The C API is documented here https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html#P4, then I would go for [Table Manipulation](https://www.lua.org/pil/25.1.html)

Comment: `lua_next` is the function you are looking for: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lua_next](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_next) for this. When you initially push `nil` onto the Lua stack and invoke `lua_next` in a while-loop, you'll be able to get each key-value pair in the table.

After each successful call to `lua_next`, the value will be on top of the stack and the key will be right below it. If you want to keep on iterating over all pairs, you'll have to pop the value from the stack but **leave the key on**. This way, `lua_next` can determine the next key to visit.

You can also break out of the iteration, by popping both the key and value from the stack and breaking the while loop.

Below you will find a short example matching your table from your question.

```
void log_color(lua_State* L, const std::string& key) {
    auto table_idx = lua_absindex(L, -1);
    if (lua_type(L, table_idx) != LUA_TTABLE || lua_rawlen(L, table_idx) != 3) {
        lua_pop(L, 2); /* pop table and key */
        luaL_error(L, "key %s requires a table with 3 numeric values", key.c_str());
    }

    auto ttr = lua_rawgeti(L, table_idx, 1);
    auto ttg = lua_rawgeti(L, table_idx, 2);
    auto ttb = lua_rawgeti(L, table_idx, 3);

    if (ttr != LUA_TNUMBER || ttg != LUA_TNUMBER || ttb != LUA_TNUMBER) {
        lua_pop(L, 5); /* pop the 3 color values, the table and the key */
        luaL_error(L, "the values for key %s should be all numeric", key.c_str());
    }
    
    std::cout << "found key " << key << " with rgb value " << lua_tonumber(L, -3) << ", " << lua_tonumber(L, -2) << ", " << lua_tonumber(L, -1) << "\n";
    lua_pop(L, 3);
}

int myMaterialFunction(lua_State* L) {
    std::string key;

    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

    // push nil for lua_next to indicate it needs to pick the first key 
    lua_pushnil(L);

    while (lua_next(L, 1)) {
        // key is at -2 on the stack, value at -1. We need to pop the value, 
        // but leave the key on the stack so that lua_next knows where to 
        // continue. You can do anything to process them at this point. 

        // i.e. when the key is not a string, ignore it;
        if (lua_type(L, -2) != LUA_TSTRING) {
            lua_pop(L, 1); /* pop the value */ 
            continue;
        }

        // and then start processing the value if its key is a string;
        key = lua_tostring(L, -2);
        if (key == "color") {
            log_color(L, key); /* process a color table */
        } else if (key == "specular_intensity" || key == "shininess") {
            // process a numeric value 
            if (lua_type(L, -1) != LUA_TNUMBER) {
                lua_pop(L, 2);
                luaL_error(L, "key %s requires a numeric value", key.c_str());
            } else {
                std::cout << "found key " << key << " with value " << lua_tonumber(L, -1) << "\n";
            }
        }

        // pop the value when you're done with it 
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```